# Run in Coverage by default

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a working configuration that runs JUnit tests through Gradle.

I can run it with Coverage to get coverage results.

My goal is to make it *always* run with Coverage, even when I don't explicitly say so (but only this configuration, not all configurations).

It is possible? If so, how? I expect it's a simple setting somewhere but I didn't find anything about that on the official website.

Comment: What Run configuration do you use for running coverage? If you run it by IDE - there is a separate mode for each run configuration that you should start to [run it with coverage](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-coverage.html).

Comment: I know, that's not the issue. If I push the run with coverage button, it works fine. But I can't run it with coverage by default, for example in the "run configuration" quick list, it appears as a normal configuration and not a coverage one